# Use keyword and dynamic class names

Tags: php, oop

```
use my\Project\FooClass;

$obj = new FooClass(); // ok
$name = 'FooClass';
$obj2 = new $name(); // throws an error that the class wasn't found
```

Well, I believe the title and the example were pretty enough explanation of my question, so just - why does this throws an error, and how should I deal with this?

Comment: Can you just omit the () ?

Comment: I use this technique all the time with no issue the only difference is I haven't tried it with namespaces. Try setting $name to the namespaced classname `my\Project\FooClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible due to the way PHP imports/aliases from namespaces. This can be remedied by using literal namespace definitions, though it no doubt sucks.

As follows:

```
$r = "my\\Project\\FooClass";
$k = new $r();
```

There is a patch in the works, or at the very least, it was on PHP's bug report a couple of months back. They will hopefully do something about it.

If it bothers you, you can use `class_alias()` to remedy it, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$obj2 = new $name;
```

Remove the parenthesis

Alternatively:

```
$obj2 = new {$name}();
```

Comment: What does the syntax error say? I use `$obj = new $someClass;` in my own applications and it works fine! Weird!

Comment: I meant the alternative - new {$name}();

Comment: Both should work in the same way, `{$name}` is the same as `$name`.

Comment: No .. The curly braces can be used in a "" string though

Comment: I have PHP 5.4.7 installed, and "$obj2 = new {$name}();" throws me a parse error :P

Comment: @nl-x curly braces can be used without quotes, I've just tested it ;) `<?php $test = 'hello world'; echo {$test}; /* Outputs: hello world */ ?>`  ... Actually, just tested it on an online sandbox, seems to produce a syntax error. Still, should work in some situations.

Comment: @PhilCross Even if it would work , I seriously doubt it has the same meaning. As { } in normal code would just indicate a code block. (In some languages even a scoped block, but not in PHP.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't explain why this doesn't work. But for how to deal with it:

```
$name = 'FooClass';
$name = "my\\Project\\FooClass\\" . $name; // prepend namespace
$obj2 = new $name();
```